# Documenting Literal Types in Python for IDE Tooltips

Tags: python, python-typing

Using Python's `TypedDict`, one can easily constrain the input dictionaries and provide documentation for each dictionary key:

```py
import typing

class MyType(typing.TypedDict):
   a: str
   """Parameter a"""
   b: int
   """Parameter b"""

def fun(x: MyType):
   ...
```

Most IDEs will list all possible declared keys, and keys' documentation can be displayed in tooltips.

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Now, let's consider a similar approach for string literals. Suppose we have the following function:

```py
import typing

def fun(x: typing.Literal["a", "b", "c"]):
   ...
```

In my IDE (VS Code), it hints at all possible inputs, i.e., `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`. Is there a way to document these parameters and have it displayed in tooltips, similar as for `TypedDict` example?

Comment: You mean so you could see for e.g. `fun("a")` what `"a"` actually _means_? Probably you just want a [`StrEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) (in which case the name of the member may be sufficient, and you can add docstrings to the members otherwise): https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=fe6645084effac3bc9be9c8fdd36a576.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for providing a solution. However, it doesn't fully meet my requirements. I would like to keep my function's input as a (literal) `str`, rather than using `Enum`. Nevertheless, your input was valuable, and I appreciate your effort.

I've been pondering if there's a way to display tooltips for each possible argument as in my example with `TypedDict`.

Comment: Purely from a syntax standpoint, where would you put them? You could do something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=f670eccfc65a610d0505282e56a08f99) but PyCharm wouldn't show those docstrings as you were writing the function call.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Interesting approach. It is sad that it does not work. I've checked in the VS code too, same result. Probably one needs to write IDE extension/plugin to support my issue from the question...

Comment: "one can easily constrain" - no. Type annotations are **only** used by third party tools and have **no meaningful effect** at runtime and **do not impact** on compilation. The only observable effect they have at runtime is to set special `__annotations__` attributes. Anything else you're seeing is specific to your third-party tooling, such as your IDE.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I'm aware of that. By "easily constrain," I meant to use it with `mypy`, of course.